# Is instantiation required for function overriding?

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What exactly is late-static binding in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912902/what-exactly-is-late-static-binding-in-php)

In this example, PHP will print "NO" rather than "YES", opposite of what I expected.

If I remove `static` on `function c()`, replace `self::` with `$this->` and do `$e = new B; $e->c();`, things will work.

Does this mean that instantiation is required to make functions in parent classes call overridden functions in inherited classes?

(Side question: Is this a PHP quirk, or does this logic also apply for most other programming languages? If so, what is the rationale behind it?)

```
class A {
  static function c() {
    self::d();
  }
  static function d() {
    echo "NO :(\n";
  }
}

class B extends A {
  static function d() {
    echo "YES :)\n";
  }
}

B::c();
```

Comment: It's not `self::d()` but `static::d()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `static` keyword instead of `self` or `$this`.

```
<?php

class A {
    static function c() {
        static::d();
    }
    static function d() {
        echo "NO :(\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
     static function d() {
         echo "YES :)\n";
     }
}

B::c();

// YES :)
```

This behavior is called [Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).