# self:: referring to derived class in static methods of a parent class

Tags: php, static-methods, multiple-constructors

I liked the idea presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1701337/2088851) allowing having something like multiple constructors in PHP. The code I have is similar to:

```
class A {
    protected function __construct(){
    // made protected to disallow calling with $aa = new A()
    // in fact, does nothing
    }; 

    static public function create(){
        $instance = new self();
        //... some important code
        return $instance;
    }

    static public function createFromYetAnotherClass(YetAnotherClass $xx){
        // ...
    } 

class B extends A {};

$aa = A::create();
$bb = B::create();
```

Now I want to create a derived class `B`, which would use the same "pseudo-constructor", because it is the same code. However, in this case when I do not code the `create()` method, the `self` constant is the class `A`, so both variables `$aa` and `$bb` are of class `A`, while I wish `$bb` be class `B`.

If I use `$this` special variable, this of course would be class `B`, even in `A` scope, if I call any parent method from `B`.

I know I can copy the entire `create()` method (maybe Traits do help?), but I also have to copy all "constructors" (all `create*` methods) and this is stupid.

How can I help `$bb` to become `B`, even if the method is called in `A` context?

Comment: You're looking for [Late Static Bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1912902/1233508).

Comment: Perhaps you want `static` instead of `self`?

Comment: @bishop Thanks - it worked. Could you please create an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix No, `parent` is wrong, as I want to go downwards, to a child, not to parent, but `static` worked perfectly, thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `static`, which represents the class in which the method is *called*.  (`self` represents the class in which the method is *defined*.)

```
static public function create(){
    $instance = new static();
    //... some important code
    return $instance;
}
```

Refer to the documentation on [Late Static Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1912902/1233508).

You'll need PHP 5.3+ to use this.