# Method Overriding vs Late Static Binding?

Tags: php, oop

When it comes with Inheritance, what Exactly is the difference between method overriding and late static binding?

Comment: Please google these terms. There's loads of resources available to you which explain them in depth if you'd just search for them.

Comment: Sure, But stack overflow community can give a batter answer.

Comment: No, you're just being lazy and not bothering to make some research effort.

Comment: If only there was some website that you could search and it would find you a result like this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late static binding is essentially method overriding for static methods. There are some subtle differences in how they are actually carried out by the compiler. See [What exactly are late static bindings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912902/what-exactly-are-late-static-bindings-in-php)