# PHP late static binding scope confusion

Tags: php

From PHP [mannual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) second paragraph, it says that:

> static:: introduces its scope.

I tried the following example accordingly:

```
class Father {
    public function test(){
        echo static::$a;
    }
}

class Son extends Father{
    protected static $a='static forward scope';
    public function test(){
        parent::test();
    }
}

$son = new Son();
$son->test(); // print "static forward scope"
```

It works as described. However, the following example will raise a fatal error:

```
class Father {
    public function test(){
        echo static::$a;
    }
}

class Son extends Father{
    private static $a='static forward scope';
    public function test(){
        parent::test();
    }
}

// print "Fatal erro: Cannot access private property Son::$a"
$son = new Son();
$son->test();
```

My main question is how to interpret the word `scope` here? If `static` introduces `Son`'s scope to `Father`, then why private variables are still invisible to `Father`?

Are there two things `variable` scope and `visibility` scope? I'm new to PHP sorry if this sounds funny.

Comment: Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912902/what-exactly-are-late-static-bindings-in-php ?

Comment: Despite of `introducing scope` `private` properties are not visible to any other classes.

Comment: @ponury-kostek tks for the reference. I read it. But l think my question is different from that thread.

Comment: Try class abstraction as described here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Comment: @u_mulder. Tks for your answer! However would you please explain the internal mechanism? I'm still confused by the behavior that `static` can introduce scope but not `visibility`.

Comment: Check the docs on visbility. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: It refers to the scope of a class name resolution, not to the scope of variable access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things at play here: scope and visibility.  Both together decide if you can access the property.

As you found in your first test, late static binding lets `$a` be available in the **scope** of the `Father` class.  That simply means the variable (not necessarily its value) is "known" to this class.

**Visibility** decides whether the variables in scope can be accessed by particular classes and instances.  A private property is only visible to the class in which it is defined.  In your second example, `$a` is defined `private` within `Son`.  Whether or not any other class is aware it exists, it can not be accessed outside of `Son`.

`static` makes `$a` a property which is known to `Father`, but the property's visibility decides whether or not its value can be accessed.

As a test to further help understand it, try using `self` instead of `static`.  You'll get back a different error that `$a` is not a property of `Father`.