# Returning of new $this with abstract classes

Tags: php, abstract-class

I found some trouble with my code and do not understand why it's doing as it is. Can anyone explain me?

Let we have:

```
abstract class AbstractThing
{
    public function search(...)
    {
        $ret = false;

        $data = $database->query(...);
        foreach($data as $values)
        {
            $item  = new $this;
            $item->fill_with_values($values);

            $ret []= $item;
        }

        return $ret;
    }
}
```

It's works as intended and return object instances at success searches:

```
class Thing extends AbstractThing
{
    // ...
}

$thing = new Thing;
$things = $thing->search(...); // Thing[] on success, false on failure
```

But if I wish to shorten code very slightly, it breaks:

```
abstract class AbstractThing
{
    public function search(...)
    {
        $ret = false;

        $data = $database->query(...);
        foreach($data as $values) {
            $ret []= (new $this)->fill_with_values($values);
        }

        return $ret;
    }
}
```

This return boolean true. Why? It works well on the classes that are not inherited from abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we assign:

```
$ret []= (new $this)->fill_with_values($values);
```

...we're not setting `$ret[] = (new $this)`. Instead, this statement pushes the return value of `fill_with_values()` into the array because it executes last.

It looks like you're trying to implement something similar to the [*factory method pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Consider this:

```
abstract class AbstractThing
{ 
    ...
    public static function fill($values) 
    { 
        $instance = new static; 
        $instance->fill_with_values($values);

        return $instance; 
    }
}
```

Then we can *actually* do what you're trying to accomplish in your question like this:

```
$ret[] = static::fill($values);
```

This works because the return value of `fill()` is the instance of the class, not the return value of `fill_with_values()`. The `static` keyword in this context uses *late static binding* to resolve the type of the class that executes the code (`Thing` in this case) instead of the class that declares it, so it works through inheritance. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912902/what-exactly-are-late-static-bindings-in-php#1913030) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand (and used before) mechanics with the static methods. Btw, `fill_with_values()` returns `$this`, it can't return `true`. At both calls data is equal. I just curious about this.

Comment: Hmm... something else must be happening inside `fill_with_values()` or `search()`. I just tested your second example (minus the database query) using a `fill_with_values()` that returns `$this` and I see the expected array of `Thing`s.

Comment: Narrowed the "trouble" a little: `$ret = new $this; $ret->_fill($data);` works, `$ret = (new $this)->_fill($data)` raises `Call to a member function _fill() on boolean` error. So, in some way (new $this) returns `true`.

Comment: Perplexing...which version of of PHP does this occur in? It sounds like a bug in the language. Here are a couple of debugging suggestions, but based on the info on this question it seems like the problem may be elsewhere: try `var_dump(new $this)`...is it a boolean? Check `AbstractThing` subclasses for a method that overrides these methods.

Comment: Funny that I can't reproduce it from scratch with the tiny classes. Using `PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )` on Docker. Thanks a lot for your replies!

Answer (score 1):

The code does 2 different things:

This adds $item to your "$ret" array:

```
        $item  = new $this;
        $item->fill_with_values($values);

        $ret []= $item;
```

This adds the returned value of "fill_with_values" to your array:

```
$ret []= (new $this)->fill_with_values($values);
```

The equivalent of the above code would be:

```
        $item  = new $this;
        $return = $item->fill_with_values($values);
        $ret []= $return;
```

If I knew what was going on in your "fill_with_values" method I could tell you why it is a boolean, but the code does not do the same thing.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to said: fill_with_values() returns $this

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally it was my own error. There was really possibility to return TRUE from fill_with_values() function at some point. Sorry all for bad questions and thanks for answers!